# Dynamically change thr URL of the Pin It (Pinterest) button

Tags: javascript, jquery, social-networking, pinterest

I'm currently trying to add social networks's buttons to my website but I've encountered an issue with the Pin It button from Pintesrest. I'd like to dynamically change the URL of the pin but unfortunately, it seems to not working. Did I do something wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var urlpin = document.location.href;

    function buildPinUrl(urlpin, urlmedia, description) {
       return '//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?'+
                'url='+encodeURIComponent(urlpin)+
                '&media='+encodeURIComponent(urlmedia)+
                '&description='+encodeURIComponent(description);
        }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var urlmedia = $("#stamp1").attr("src");
        var description = $("#title").text();
        var goodurl = buildPinUrl(urlpin, urlmedia, description);

        $('#pinbtn').attr('href', goodurl);

    });

</script>
```

And here the button:

```
<!-- Pin It Button --><a id="pinbtn" href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcollectionnies.com&media=http%3A%2F%2Fcollectionnies.com&description=Next%20stop%3A%20Collectionnies" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="beside"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" /></a><!-- Pin It Button -->
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery 1.6+ (up to edge), this works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmKcR/

Check to make sure that jQuery is loaded before this code appears in the html.  Also make sure you are not loading jQuery in noConflict mode, as this will break the use of the $.

If this still fails for you, use the Chrome/Firefox inspector to view any console errors.

If you see an error like:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

One of the two above issues is at fault.

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.9.1.js
It is loaded just after the opening body tag
I don't think it's in noConflict mode because I use the $ before and it works perfectly.
And I don't have any error.
I'm running on Mozilla Firefox.
I really don't know where I went wrong, especially if you're making it work in jsFiddle :/

Comment: It's working fine in jquery-1.9.1 anyway. See the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/HbmTs/1/

Comment: The JS that Pinterest wanted me to add to my site was preventing the url changing! Thanks for you help!

Comment: Not a problem.  Remember, the inspector should be your first stop for all JavaScript related issues.  If you can not find a clear explanation/solution by viewing the Console (really, about 75% of the time you will find your answer here), it at the very least gives you solid errors and information to present here on SO to get help quickly.